# Ubuntu to W8 Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!

Tags: windows-8, live-usb

I made a liveUSB on ubuntu 14.04. I am trying to boot Windows 8 from a flash drive and I get this message. I see the conversion for the linux. Is there one for the windows?

Comment: what message do you get? please post the message, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Live USB will not support create windows boot USB from Ubuntu. It allow to create only Linux boot USB from Windows.

Try **winusb**,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:colingille/freshlight
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/colingille-freshlight-trusty.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winusb
```

With **winusb** you can do your need.

Comment: Is there another application that I could use?

Comment: @user2649490 I have updated.. please check answer.. if your problem solved accept the answer...

Comment: Does this work with W8 because I cant get it to see the iso

Comment: @user2649490 do you have W8 ISO file ?

Comment: Just the 8.1 enterprise trial image